# How to shorten repeated functions

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make this code more efficient or shorter. I feel like there are too much repeated functions. Is there a way to make this all in one and shorter?

```
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Audio 1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Audio 2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction3()">Audio 3</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var a = new Audio('Link1');
    a.play();
}

function myFunction2() {
    var b = new Audio('Link2');
    b.play();
}

function myFunction3() {
    var c = new Audio('Link3');
    c.play();
}

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: pass `Link1/2/3` to the function and you can just use one function `myFunction('Link1')` for example

Comment: I would advise heavily against this. JavaScript in HTML becomes a major problem with maintenance and goes against the oft-cited "separation of concerns"

Comment: @zfrisch Can you clarify what exactly you are advising against? The use of JavaScript in general?

Comment: @MrLister Event Attributes on HTML Elements. They are fine if used in random bits of test code, and I suppose I should've been clear about that, but as a rule I wouldn't use them in production code due to the inability to maintain the code at a later date by the Developer, and this is  especially true if any other Developers are brought in at any point to help out. Basically If you separate your code from your markup(which you should) you may end up looking in the wrong place to alter things if you use Event Attributes.

Comment: @zfrisch OK, that I agree with. Glad that's cleared up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a parameter to the function for the link.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="playAudio('link1')">Audio 1</button>
<button onclick="playAudio('link2')">Audio 2</button>
<button onclick="playAudio('link3')">Audio 3</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function playAudio(link) {
    var audio = new Audio(link);
    audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using function call parameter, try following:

```
<button onclick="doPlay(1)">Audio 1</button>
<button onclick="doPlay(2)">Audio 2</button>
<button onclick="doPlay(3)">Audio 3</button>


function doPlay(index) {
    var a = new Audio('Link' + index);
    a.play();
}
```

Comment: @qttqtt just through [function parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp): I'm passing appropriate `index` (1, 2, 3) to the `doPlay`, so...

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Using `index` param (1, 2, 3) is more generic than `token` param ('link1' etc), cause `token` could be changed (e.g 'myPrettyLink1' etc) while `index` is just an index.